# React-Native hide navbar when scrolling

Tags: scroll, react-native, navbar

I'm using react-native-navigation-flux navigation library,
and I'm trying to implement that the navbar will disappear when scrolling down.
Is it possible to achieve that?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt, so we can try to solve your problem and explain why your own attempt failed - that way you can learn something useful for your future development, as well as getting an answer to this single problem.

Answer (score 3):

Try using Animation and set navigationBar height to zero on scrollup and default height on scrolldown.

```
 class MyAwesomeComponent extends Component {

   constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.height = new Animated.Value(100);
   }

   _setAnimation(enable) {
     Animated.timing(this.height, {
       duration: 400,
       toValue: enable? 100 : 0
     }).start()
   } 

   render() {
     return (
       <Animated.View style={{ height: this.height }}/>
     );
  }

}
```